# How to authorize a program to make changes with powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script that allows me to automate some steps on the registry editor, but I'm stuck after this line of code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\Registry Editor.lnk"
```

After that, the computer shows a pop up and and don't know how via PowerShell click on the "Yes" button, like this one:
[image]

How can my script "select" the "yes" option?

Comment: How will you navigate the registry editor with PowerShell once you've managed to programmatically click "Yes"? :) If you want to automate registry changes then you'll want to use PowerShell's built-in [registry provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider?view=powershell-5.1) instead of launching graphical management tools

Comment: I'm trying to add a new program to the context menu. I used this tutorial [link](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/add-any-program-windows-context-menu/#:~:text=Add%20Any%20Program%20to%20Context,adding%20to%20the%20context%20menu.) and I would like to create a shortcut that opens and runs a python script.

Comment: That can certainly be done, the article I linked above describes [how to create registry keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_registry_provider?view=powershell-5.1#creating-registry-keys-and-values) using PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: The only way to avoid [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) prompts is to either run in an elevated process to begin with or to disable UAC altogether, _which is strongly discouraged_.  Otherwise, there's only a limited workaround: Assuming that you are an administrator in principle, you can set up a scheduled task with a preconfigured command to be run with elevation, which you can then invoke on demand from a non-elevated session of yours without triggering a UAC prompt.